# How can I change the background color of a row from my datagridview if column 1 holds a string with "Aborted"?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Good day people of stackoverflow,

I am building a GUI and in this GUI I have a datagridview which shows data from a database. However I am looking for a way to change the color of an entire row to red when the first column of that row holds the string "Aborted".

I've tried finding a solution to this, however all examples have been conditions with Integers instead of Strings.

**This is my current piece of code for the coloring:**

```
private void datagridview1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Value as string == "Aborted")
    {
        var style = datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;
        style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

However this does not change the color of the column or the entire row that holds the value Aborted nor does it even give an error message...

Even in the Events Properties of the `datagridview1` next to `CellFormatting` it shows `datagridview1_CellFormatting` so it surely is bound to the datagridview.

**Screenshot**
[Events Properties of the datagridview1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUudW.png)

**Screenshot of the datagridview**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MCG4.png)

Does anyone have a solution to this? I have absolutely no idea what is going wrong.

EDIT: quick screenshot of an error
[Error of @Jimi's example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54uh.png)

Comment: Did you actually set a breakpoint inside the `if` condition, to check whether that code is actually executed? -- If you need to change the colors of an entire Row, handle the `RowPrePaint` or `RowPostPaint` events instead. Try to subscribe to the latter (commenting out the code in `CellFormatting`) and write `if ((sender as DataGridView)[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() == "Aborted") { // The rest }`. Set a breakpoint inside there

Comment: And how would I subscribe to the event? Isn't adding it in the Properties > Events tab not enough?

Comment: Find the event name in the PropertyGrid, double-click the corresponding cell on the right and VS creates the handler for you -- Don't forget to set a breakpoint in there (inside the `if` condition)

Comment: That's what I had done. So I am confused why the code did not change the color of the row then...

The datagridviews I use are inside of a tablelayoutpanel, would that affect it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Did you do what I've described, breakpoint included?

Comment: Yes it does break now, I added a screenshot of what it looks like to the main post

Comment: Yes, but does it enter the `if` block? I.e., is that condition actually met at some point? Did you step in after the breakpoint is hit?

Comment: Just tried it, and no it doesn't seem like it.

I added Messagebow.Show after the if statement and it didn't create a message box. So it seems the if statement isn't working.

(I just copied the messagebox from an other project so I am 100% sure that is supposed to work)

Comment: Seems like I am a complete idiot. I grabbed the Output debugger and saw 0 : "Aborted" fly by... I should have had column 0 not 1... So it actually does work...

Thank you for your time and effort and sorry for wasting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of Oliver works great if you wish to only color the column that has "Aborted", however the solution to color the entire row is as follows (Many thanks to [u/JTarsier](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/xojf6s/comment/is2r37r/) from Reddit)

```
// Use the event CellFormatting from Datagridview > Properties > Events
private void datagridview1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Use this one liner to check which number is associated with which column
    //(so you don't make the mistake of trying to use the wrong column like me ._.)
    
    // Debug.WriteLine($"{e.ColumnIndex} : '{e.Value}'");
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Value as string == "Aborted")
    {
        var style = datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle;
        style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        style.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating the wrong style object. Try this:

```
private void datagridview1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.Value as string == "Aborted")
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sadly didn't work. No error, but it also didn't change the color. Could it be some setting in the properties tab of the datagridview that I am missing?

Also, this datagridview is inside of a tablelayoutpanel (in case that matters).

Comment: Ehrm, it seems I should have been looking at column 0 and not column 1 at the if statement. So yes this does indeed work (however it only color's the first column and not the entire row)